# Relation between $\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom {n+k}{k}a_k $ and $\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom {n+k}{k}\frac{a_k}{k}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series

Let  $\{a_k\}(k\ge 0)$ be a sequence of nonzero real numbers which changes signs infinitely often. Suppose $|a_k|\to 0 $ and $|a_k|$ decreases fast. Let $n$ be a positive integer. What's the relation between
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom {n+k}{k}a_k $$ and $$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom {n+k}{k}\frac{a_k}{k}. $$ For the asymptotic behavior, as $n\to \infty$, are $$\frac{\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom {n+k}{k}a_k}{\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom {n+k}{k}\frac{a_k}{k}}=O(1)$$ and
$$\frac{\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom {n+k}{k}a_k}{\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom {n+k}{k}\frac{a_k}{k}}=O(\frac{n}{\log n})$$ true or not? I tried to use Abel's summation formula, but it seems that Abel's summation formula is not applicable and I don't find relevant references.

Comment: You definitely should assume something additional about $a_k$'s, like positivity and the fast decay

Comment: $a_k$ may change signs, but $|a_k|$ decreases fast.

Comment: Let $f(x) := \sum_{k\geq0} \binom{n+k}k \frac{a_k}k x^k$. Then the former sum is $f'(1)$, while the latter is $f(1)$. And $\frac{f'(1)}{f(1)} = \left.\log(f(x))'\right|_{x=1}$.

Comment: Dear Alekseyev, thank you. I know this, but I want to know the asymptotic behavior of the quotient as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: The conjectured asymptotics are almost certainly false, as it will not be difficult to make the denominator vanish for infinitely many (but sufficiently sparse) set of $n$ without making the numerator vanish.

Comment: Btw, the second sum cannot start at $k=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the second sum cannot start at $k=0$, I assume that both sums start at $k=1$.

Consider a particular example: $a_k = k\alpha^k$ with $|\alpha|<1$. Then
$$\sum_{k\geq 1} \binom{n+k}k \frac{a_k}k = (1-\alpha)^{-(n+1)}-1$$
and
$$\sum_{k\geq 1} \binom{n+k}k a_k = (n+1)(1-\alpha)^{-(n+2)}\alpha.$$
Then the ratio of the two $\approx \frac{(n+1)\alpha}{1-\alpha}$, which is not $O(\frac{n}{\log(n)})$.